# implementing ECC causes error

Tags: java, dictionary, netbeans-6.9

I am trying to implement ECC in java, but I'm getting an error.

Here is the error:

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestECC.TestECC
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)..
```

And here is the code:

```
 package com.acc;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.spec.ECGenParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.ECParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.EllipticCurve;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;


public class TestECC {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Provider p[] = Security.getProviders();
            Provider p1 = Security.getProvider("SunEC");
            System.out.println(p1.getName());
            KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", "SunEC");
            System.out.println(kpg.getAlgorithm());

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
            System.out.println("provider=" + cipher.getProvider());

            ECGenParameterSpec ecsp = new ECGenParameterSpec("sect163r2");

            kpg.initialize(ecsp);
            KeyPair kyp = kpg.genKeyPair();
            PublicKey pubKey = kyp.getPublic();

            PrivateKey privKey = kyp.getPrivate();
            System.out.println(cipher.getProvider());

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);

            String cleartextFile = "cleartext.txt";
            String ciphertextFile = "ciphertextECIES.txt";

            byte[] block = new byte[64];
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(cleartextFile);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ciphertextFile);
            CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);

            int i;
            while ((i = fis.read(block)) != -1) {
                cos.write(block, 0, i);
            }
            cos.close();

            // Decrypt

            String cleartextAgainFile = "cleartextAgainECIES.txt";

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey, ecsp);

            fis = new FileInputStream(ciphertextFile);
            CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(cleartextAgainFile);

            while ((i = cis.read(block)) != -1) {
                fos.write(block, 0, i);
            }
            fos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @DaveNewton I doubt it, after 4-5 years you should learn about packages.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to run this with:

```
java TestECC.TestECC
```

which isn't the class name. You should be running this:

```
java com.acc.TestECC
```

... that's the fully-qualified class name. Note that this has *nothing* to do with the code within your main method. You could delete all of that code and you'd still get the same error; it hasn't got as far as running any of your code yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run the class

```
java TestECC.TestECC
```

when that is not the right package name. Instead you want

```
java com.acc.TestECC
```

making sure to set your classpath correctly.  (Or use an IDE which sets this up for you)